# Inheriting 100vh or passing 100% height down the elements tree?

Tags: html, css

when building an application whose UI should always be 100% of height of the screen and scroll should be added on particular elements that are to be overflown, what is the right approach?

lets say we have a structure (pseudo):

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="firstColumn">
           </div>
           <div class="secondColumn">
           </div>
           <div class="thirdColumn">
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

so, each column should be scrollable on its own.

What is the right approach:

1) set `100vh` on body and pass `height:100%` through all children down to column?

or

2) set `100vh` on column directly and go on with `overflow:auto`?

Answer (score 4):

Option #2.

There is no need to get the `height` of the `body` involved and you wouldn't need to explicitly set `overflow:auto`. You probably want `overflow:scroll`.

Comment: visible is the default

Comment: hm...i thought `visible` is the default.

Comment: @Nomistake  was faster ;)

Comment: @deezg we were going to fast :-)